# Proper syntax for controller action with slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 3.2
```

I have a view views/tickets/show.html.slim with a number of sections. I want to have different controllers for each section, and have actions like New Save Edit

So in my views/tickets/show.html.slim, I have:

```
- @customer_info = customer_info @ticket
h4.form-header Customer Information
.form-section.attachments
  - if @customer_info.nil?
    = render partial: 'tickets/sections/customer_info', locals: {ticket:  @ticket }
```

In my view, I have:

```
= form_for CustomerInfo.new  do |f|
  - f.hidden_field :ticket_id, :value => ticket.id
  .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
    .form-group
      = f.label :first
      = f.text_field :first, maxlength: 50
    .form-group
      = f.label :last
      = f.text_field :last, maxlength: 50
    - logger.info("Marker 1")  
    .actions = link_to "Save", :controller => :customer_infos, :action => :create
    - logger.info("Marker 2")
.clear
```

When I run the application in test mode, and I select a ticket, I get the following response:

```
Incomplete response received from application
```

In my test.log file, I have:

CustomerInfo Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT ``` customer_infos``.* FROM ```customer_infos`WHERE`customer_infos`.`ticket_id` = '1466026127' LIMIT 1
Marker 1
  Rendered tickets/sections/_customer_info.html.slim (11.6ms)
  Rendered admin/tickets/show.html.slim within layouts/application (563.0ms)

There is no Marker 2

If I replace:

```
.actions = link_to "Save", :controller => :customer_infos, :action => :create
```

With:

```
    .actions = f.submit 'Save'
```

Then the form renders fine.

Any idea why this is not working?

## Attempted fix:

In my tickets/section/_customer_info.html.slim, I did:

```
.actions = link_to "Save", create_customer_info_path, method: :post
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
post '/customer_infos/create' => 'customer_infos#create', as: 'create_customer_info'
```

I am now getting the following error message:

```
undefined method `customer_infos_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000008bb54d8>:0x00000009df3c30>
```

Where is customer_infos_path coming from?

If I do rake routes, I get:

```
create_customer_info POST /customer_infos/create(.:format) customer_infos#create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), using the `controller` option is frowned upon. You should set up your route with a name, like this:

```
post '/customers/create' => 'customer_infos#create', as: 'create_customer'
```

Then your view should look something like this:

```
.actions
    = link_to "Save", create_customer_path, method: :post
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No. I am using the test environment. How do I get a stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd get a stack trace. But honestly, I don't see why you're using a `link_to` tag instead of `f.submit`. You should be able to change the path on the form tag.

Comment: This is create. I have several other controller actions I need to implement that are not the standard actions, this is why I am looking for a solution that allows me to specify a controller action

Comment: You should be able to customize the form `action` with the `url` option. For example: `= form_for CustomerInfo.new, url: your_custom_form_action_path`